# Java Lambda expression to avoid multiple iterations

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Folks,

Consider the following example, given a list of Trade objects my code needs to return an array containing trade volume for 24 hours, 7 days, 30 days and all times.

Using plain old iterator this requires only a single iteration over the collection.

I'm trying to do the same using a Java 8 streams and Lambda expressions. I came up with this code, which looks elegant, works fine, but requires 4 iterations over the list:

```
public static final int DAY = 24 * 60 * 60;

public double[] getTradeVolumes(List<Trade> trades, int timeStamp) {
    double volume = trades.stream().mapToDouble(Trade::getVolume).sum();
    double volume30d = trades.stream().filter(trade -> trade.getTimestamp() + 30 * DAY > timeStamp).mapToDouble(Trade::getVolume).sum();
    double volume7d = trades.stream().filter(trade -> trade.getTimestamp() + 7 * DAY > timeStamp).mapToDouble(Trade::getVolume).sum();
    double volume24h = trades.stream().filter(trade -> trade.getTimestamp() + DAY > timeStamp).mapToDouble(Trade::getVolume).sum();
    return new double[]{volume24h, volume7d, volume30d, volume};
}
```

How can I achieve the same using only a single iteration over the list ?

Comment: The overall question is: _Why_ would you want to do it in only one iteration?

Comment: Since it's more efficient.

Comment: Nope! It's not more efficient! I asked the question as I expected that answer. And your assumption is not correct: Who says that two iterations each doing one operation must be less efficient than only one iteration doing two operations?

Comment: Consider the case where I have 1,000,000 trades and 100 different volumes to calculate and the method trade.getTimestamp() is expensive. Using an iterator I only need to call it 1,000,000 times, while using lambda I need to call it 100 million times.

Comment: I suggest you compare/measure the performance to see what difference it makes.  It should be easy to put a test together.  It might make a big difference in which case, use a loop, or a little difference in which case do what you feel is clearer.

Comment: You might want to add a method `static double sumByAge(List<Trade> trades, int days) { return trades.stream().filter(trade -> trade.getTimestamp() + days * DAY > timeStamp).mapToDouble(Trade::getVolume).sum(); }`  This will tidy the code quite a bit.

Comment: Thanks Peter, but consider that the time required for executing trade.getTimeStamp() and trade.getVolume() is the dominating factor. Therefore the example above will take close to 4 times longer to execute than a single iteration which only calls these methods once per trade.

Comment: @lyaffe You can always switch back to the _old_ iterator mechanism (if the `getTimeStamp` method is such a big difference). The better alternative would be to optimize the `getTimeStamp` method. If - for example - the value is calculated in a complex operation, then caching this value (inside the `Trade` instance) would be an option.

Comment: Ok, I thought there is a simple solution for this but now I realize that this might be a basic limitation of Lambda expressions. Trying to state this formally, in case you need to perform more than one task, on a different subset of a collection, in a single iteration than you cannot use a Lambda expression. Would that be right ?

Comment: @lyaffe I would not consider your last statement as correct. I see your point, but unless you really proved your code to be less efficient you should not try to optimize (this is called _premature optimization_ which is considered to be evil). In fact you should always try to write the most readable code, and your four for-each lines using lambdas look very well. Try to optimize the operations that are used in the lambdas so that they run as fast as possible. In fact, also when using four loops (or maybe hundred or thousand) you are still in _time complexity O(n)_.

Answer (score 9):

This problem is similar to the "summary statistics" collector.  Take a look at the `IntSummaryStatistics` class:

```
public class IntSummaryStatistics implements IntConsumer {
    private long count;
    private long sum;
    ...

    public void accept(int value) {
        ++count;
        sum += value;
        min = Math.min(min, value);
        max = Math.max(max, value);
   }

   ...
```

}

It is designed to work with `collect()`; here's the implementation of `IntStream.summaryStatistics()`

```
public final IntSummaryStatistics summaryStatistics() {
    return collect(IntSummaryStatistics::new, IntSummaryStatistics::accept,
                   IntSummaryStatistics::combine);
}
```

The benefit of writing a `Collector` like this is then your custom aggregation can run in parallel.

Comment: That's was my initial approach but note the different filter applied before the mapping. How would you define the collector and still apply the filter ?

Comment: The accept method would conditionally increment the various sums.  Basically, you're shoveling all the data through the collector, which can pick off the bits it wants.  For sequential processing, this is basically equivalent to the for-loop, but it parallelizes cleanly whereas the for-loop does not.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Brian, I ended up implementing the code below, it's not as simple as I hoped but at least it iterates only once, its parallel ready and it passes my unit tests.
Any improvements ideas are welcomed.

```
public double[] getTradeVolumes(List<Trade> trades, int timeStamp) {
    TradeVolume tradeVolume = trades.stream().collect(
            () -> new TradeVolume(timeStamp),
            TradeVolume::accept,
            TradeVolume::combine);
    return tradeVolume.getVolume();
}

public static final int DAY = 24 * 60 * 60;

static class TradeVolume {

    private int timeStamp;
    private double[] volume = new double[4];

    TradeVolume(int timeStamp) {
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    }

    public void accept(Trade trade) {
        long tradeTime = trade.getTimestamp();
        double tradeVolume = trade.getVolume();
        volume[3] += tradeVolume;
        if (!(tradeTime + 30 * DAY > timeStamp)) {
            return;
        }
        volume[2] += tradeVolume;
        if (!(tradeTime + 7 * DAY > timeStamp)) {
            return;
        }
        volume[1] += tradeVolume;
        if (!(tradeTime + DAY > timeStamp)) {
            return;
        }
        volume[0] += tradeVolume;
    }

    public void combine(TradeVolume tradeVolume) {
        volume[0] += tradeVolume.volume[0];
        volume[1] += tradeVolume.volume[1];
        volume[2] += tradeVolume.volume[2];
        volume[3] += tradeVolume.volume[3];
    }

    public double[] getVolume() {
        return volume;
    }
}
```

Comment: You posited that `getTimestamp was the expensive part, so you could factor that out within `accept` rather than executing it three times.

Comment: Now after your edit, you are comparing `timestamp` with `timestamp` which makes no sense. If you name a local variable the same as the instance field you have to qualify the access to the latter with `this.`. And note that your conditions are related: for a positive `i` you can say that if `x+i>y` is `true` you know that `x+7*i>y` and `x+30*i>y` are `true` as well (as long as you can preclude overflow). Or if `x+30*i>y` is `false`, `x+7*i>y` and `x+i>y` must be `false` as well. So there’s room to improve your conditional code…

Comment: Fixed, I'm trying to simplify complex code into a simplified example thus causing these problems.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to use a `Collectors.groupingBy` method to partition the data however the equation would be complicated and not intent revealing.

Since `getTimestamp()` is an expensive operation, it is probably best to keep it as a pre-Java 8 iteration so you only have to calculate the value once per `Trade`.

Just because Java 8 adds shiny new tools, don't try to turn it into a hammer to hammer in all nails.